# running blender script via PHP shell_exec

Tags: ssh, blender, shell-exec

Im trying to run the following command via my PHP script

```
    $exe = "blender -b /var/www/renderer/tmp/abcd/abcd.blend -P /var/www/renderer/addon_execute.py -- -sx 300 -sy 600 -s 0.5 -sa 10";

    $res = shell_exec( $exe );
```

The result im getting is

```
Read blend: /var/www/renderer/tmp/abcd/abcd.blend 
Blender quit
```

Running the same script via SSH runs perfectly

What is wrong here ?

Comment: How do you run it (i.e. directly via `php ./your_script.php` or via web server HTTP URL)? If latter, does the first version work? E.g. it may be related to the fact that web server runs under different system account and hence have different location for `~/.config/blender`, potentially not having addons you want it to use.

Comment: via HTTP URL the first one works

Comment: There are `BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS` and `BLENDER_USER_CONFIG` environment variables that can be used to redirect userprefs and addons directories to location accessible by your web server (e.g. apache). This directories should be readable by web server user. You can create a copy of your `.config/blender` to some generic location, `chmod -R +r` on this directory and set env vars to that location (via absolute path). Probably easiest way to do that is by creating shell script with `export BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS=/path/to/userscripts/; export BLENDER_USER_CONFIG=/path/to/useprefs/; blender ...`

Comment: Where is BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS and BLENDER_USER_CONFIG are configured ?

Comment: Looks like you are relying on an installed config to enable an addon, you can install and enable addons by script. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73775/935) for an example. There is also an `--addons` [cli argument](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html).